# how to find common values in 2 multidimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

The problem is i have two 2D arrays so need to get the common values of 
 both. so how i check the common values in both arrays.

i have written nested for loop for doing this and here i 
 add some dummy array data for showing purpose:

```
 var arr1 = [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0][1,1],[1,2],[2,0],[2,2]];
 var arr2 = [[0,1],[0,0],[2,2]];

 var commonValueIndex = [];
 for(var i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
  for(var j=0; j<arr2.length; j++){
    if(arr1[i][j] == arr2[i][j]){
       commonValueIndex.push([i,j]);
     }
   }
  }
```

need to find common values and store the index of their in another array. any suggestion please.

Comment: I understand it could be that English is nor your first language, but still it is simply very difficult to understand your question. Could you go through it some more and try to clear it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a little logic error in your code.
Take a look at this line:

```
if(arr1[i][j] == arr2[i][j])
```

Here you're trying to compare the individual elements of your two arrays. Unfortunately **i** holds the current element of arr1 and **j** of arr2 - so essentially you're comparing apples to oranges here. Furthermore each element contains another array with an index of 0 and 1 you aren't comparing anywhere.

This is the correct comparison:

```
if (arr1[i][0] == arr2[j][0] && arr1[i][1] == arr2[j][1])
```

Or a full featured-example:

```js
var arr1 = [ [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 2] ];
var arr2 = [ [0, 1], [0, 0], [2, 2] ];

var commonValueIndex = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
    if (arr1[i][0] == arr2[j][0] && arr1[i][1] == arr2[j][1]) {
      // if you want the actual values
      commonValueIndex.push([arr1[i][0], arr1[i][1]]);
      // if you want the indices
      // commonValueIndex.push([i, j]);
    }
  }
}
console.log(commonValueIndex);
```

which will output the proper common values

> [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1 ], [ 2, 2 ] ]

Comment: Glad I could help. =)

Answer (score 2):

Beside the nearly quadratic approaches, you could take a map with stringified arrays and check against the other array in a single loop. Then just filter the items without finding the same values in the other array out.

```js
var array1 = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0][1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 2]],
    array2 = [[0, 1], [0, 0], [2, 2]],
    map = new Map(array2.map((v, i) => [JSON.stringify(v), i])),
    indices = array1
        .map((v, i) => map.has(JSON.stringify(v)) && [i, map.get(JSON.stringify(v))])
        .filter(Boolean),
    common = array1.filter(v => map.has(JSON.stringify(v)));

console.log(indices);
console.log(common);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This will output `[ [ 0, 1 ], [ 1, 0 ], [ 6, 2 ]` - and [6,2] doesn't exist in either of those two arrays.

Comment: that are indices of `array1` and `array2`.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now - I thought Mujitha Manorathna was after the actual values.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem correctly, then you want to store the index of matching values in `arr1` and `arr2`. If yes, then you need to update your `if` condition to following

```js
var arr1 = [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0][1,1],[1,2],[2,0],[2,2]];
var arr2 = [[0,1],[0,0],[2,2]];
var commonValueIndex = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
    if (arr1[i][0] == arr2[j][0] && arr1[i][1] == arr2[j][1]) {
      commonValueIndex.push([i, j]);
    }
  }
}
console.log(commonValueIndex);
```

Comment: Glad to help you!